# Hiding Side Menu Upon Browser Resizing

Tags: jquery

User clicks the link "table of contents" and it appears as a side menu.
If the browser resizes below 1448px then the side menu does a fadeOut().

So, after having clicked the "table of contents" link, resizing the browser below 1448px, then resizing above 1448px...

How can I get the side menu to automatically fadeIn() again?

```
    var button = $("a#contents_link"); // the TOC link
    var toc = $('#table-of-contents'); // the TOC div to show
    var browser = $(window);           // getting the browser width


    toc.hide();                         // hide the TOC div upon loading the page

    button.click(function (event) {    // toggling the TOC div
        toc.fadeToggle(300);
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });

    $(browser).resize(function() {
        if ( (toc.is(':visible')) && (browser.width() >=1449) ) {
            toc.fadeIn();
        } else if( (toc.is(':visible')) && (browser.width() <=1448) ){ 
            toc.fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your code where you check visibility of the TOC in the first IF statement.  Shouldn't you rewrite this as:

```
$(browser).resize(function() {
    if ( (toc.is(':hidden')) && (browser.width() >=1449) ) {
        toc.fadeIn();
    } else if( (toc.is(':visible')) && (browser.width() <=1448) ){ 
        toc.fadeOut();
    }
});
```